# Using JSON descriptors how to define an array in gRPC?

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm using JSON descriptors instead of proto format. Everithing works, unless the array of Todo. I need an array of Todos.
How define that? I put the "type": "array", but always return the error:
'Error: no such Type or Enum 'array' in Type .Todos'

My json file is like this:

```
const todo = {
    "nested": {
        "Services": {
            "methods": {
                "createTodo": {
                    "requestType": "Todo",
                    "requestStream": false,
                    "responseType": "Todo",
                    "responseStream": false
                },
                "readTodos": {
                    "requestType": "voidNoParam",
                    "requestStream": false,
                    "responseType": "Todos",
                    "responseStream": false
                },
                "readTodosStream": {
                    "requestType": "voidNoParam",
                    "requestStream": false,
                    "responseType": "Todo",
                    "responseStream": true
                }
            }
        },
        "Todo": {
            "fields": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "int32",
                    "id": 1
                },
                "text": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "id": 2
                }
            }
        },
        "Todos": {
            "fields": {
                "items": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "id": 1
                }
            }
        },
        "voidNoParam": {
            "fields": {}
        }
    }
}
module.exports = todo
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, really simple.

```
"Todos": {
            "fields": {
                "items": {
                    "rule": "repeated",
                    "type": "Todo",
                    "id": 1
                }
            }
        },
```